# Написал бота на раздачу ролей, никаких ошибок не выдаёт, но при нажатии на реакцию или наоборот ничего не делает

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import utils

import config


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                               id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

                if (len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                           id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))


# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel
    return
    if reaction.emoji == "":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="YOUR_ROLE_NAME_HERE")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Только заметьте, что где я написал **YOUR_CHANNEL_ID** укажите ID канала. А в строке `if reaction.emoji == "":` в кавычки добавьте эмодзи, которым нужно реагировать чтобы получить роль. Прошу прощения, что просто не исправил вашу функцию. Но вы можете сами настроить код, который я отправил под себя.

Comment: Мой ответ помог?